# JavaScript - How do I remove objects from an array that contain a specific string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

My array has several objects. Some of the objects contain a specific string, if the object contains this specific string I want it to be removed from the array.

I tried to use a **while** to loop and find all of the indexes of the array that have "Smelly" and then splice each one.

In the end I want the array to only contain

```
[  
    name: "Tiffany", status: "Clean",
    name: "Space-man", status: "Clean",
    name: "Soap-man", status: "Clean",
]
```

```js
let myArray = [
     {name: "Timmy", status: "Smelly"},
     {name: "Tiffany", status: "Clean"},
     {name: "Kyle", status: "Smelly"},
     {name: "Space-man", status: "Clean"},
     {name: "Soap-man", status: "Clean"},
]

while (i = 0) {
  try {
    let find = myArray.findIndex(i => i.status === `Smelly`);
    myArray.splice(find, 1);
  } catch {
    i = 1;
  }
}
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: Just filter it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter as:

```js
 let myArray = [
 {name: "Timmy", status: "Smelly"},
 {name: "Tiffany", status: "Clean"},
 {name: "Kyle", status: "Smelly"},
 {name: "Space-man", status: "Clean"},
 {name: "Soap-man", status: "Clean"},
 ]

let result = myArray.filter(i => i.status !== 'Smelly');
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result using `Array.filter`

```js
const value = [
  {name: "Timmy", status: "Smelly"},
  {name: "Tiffany", status: "Clean"},
  {name: "Kyle", status: "Smelly"},
  {name: "Space-man", status: "Clean"},
  {name: "Soap-man", status: "Clean"}
];

const result = value.filter((item) => item.status !== 'Smelly');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter it

You can choose to create a new filtered array or replace the existing one

```js
let myArray = [ {name: "Timmy", status: "Smelly"}, {name: "Tiffany", status: "Clean"}, {name: "Kyle", status: "Smelly"}, {name: "Space-man", status: "Clean"}, {name: "Soap-man", status: "Clean"}]

// filter into a new array

const cleanArray = myArray.filter(item => item.status !== "Smelly")

console.log(cleanArray)
 
// or replace:
 
myArray = myArray.filter(item => item.status !== "Smelly")

console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to kee the object reference of the array, you could iterate from the end of the array.

[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) changes the indices if spliced from start.

```js
let array = [{ name: "Timmy", status: "Smelly" }, { name: "Tiffany", status: "Clean" }, { name: "Kyle", status: "Smelly" }, { name: "Space-man", status: "Clean" }, { name: "Soap-man", status: "Clean" }],
    i = array.length;

while (i--) if (array[i].status === `Smelly`) array.splice(i, 1);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That sounds a LOT heavier than `array = array.filter(...)`

Comment: But so does array = array.filter()

Comment: Ok, if you say so. Any this is important why?

Comment: because op wants to splice. this does not change the reference.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to have a boolean in the while loop. So you can add a counter starting from 0 and run the loop while the counter is less than the length of the array .

Here is the code:

```js
let myArray = [
    { name: "Timmy", status: "Smelly" },
    { name: "Tiffany", status: "Clean" },
    { name: "Kyle", status: "Smelly" },
    { name: "Space-man", status: "Clean" },
    { name: "Soap-man", status: "Clean" },
]

let counter = 0;

while (counter < myArray.length) {
  let find = myArray.findIndex(i => i.status === `Smelly`);
  if (find != -1) {
    myArray.splice(find, 1);
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
}

myArray.forEach(el => console.log(el));
```

Comment: that is far too complicated for something so simple

Answer (score 0):

**`splice` is expensive.** It has to shift all subsequent elements after the one you've removed. And you do that in a loop.

Most of the time I'd go with [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It's simple and it's safe; no unexpected side effects when I "remove" items from a list *(like something disappearing because I forgot, that some other code also uses this list)*.

But sometimes I explicitely want or need to mutate the list itself. Here's a little utility function for that:

Like splice it shifts all elements towards the low indices, and like filter it keeps only the elements that match the predicate.

```js
const value = [
  {name: "Timmy", status: "Smelly"},
  {name: "Tiffany", status: "Clean"},
  {name: "Kyle", status: "Smelly"},
  {name: "Space-man", status: "Clean"},
  {name: "Soap-man", status: "Clean"}
];

function filterInPlace(array, predicate) {
  let j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    if (i in array && predicate(array[i], i, array)) {
      if (i !== j) {
        array[j] = array[i];
      }
      ++j;
    }
  }
  array.length = j;
  return array;
}

const result = filterInPlace(value, (item) => item.status !== 'Smelly');

console.log(result === value);
console.log(result);
```