# My function doesn't remove "false" after converting it to a boolean

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

I was trying to make a function that would remove all values that are "false" when converted to boolean but for some reason, "false" item doesn't get removed from the array.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let y = []
  for (let i of arr) {
    if (Boolean(i) == false) {
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(i), 1)
    }
  }
  console.log(arr)
}
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Comment: When you modify the array in the middle of the loop, you cause an element to be skipped in the iteration process.

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/64025731/6567275

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators (invoked by `for..of`) are *lazy*. They don't create a collection of all items to iterate over in the beginning. Rather, at the beginning of each iteration, they increment the index to check, and look up that index on the array.

In this case, on index 2, the `''`, being falsey, gets removed with `splice`. After splicing, the array is now:

```
[7, 'ate', false, 9]
```

Then, the iterator goes on to index 3, and checks `9`. The `false` is never iterated over.

Use `.filter` instead:

```js
const bouncer = arr => arr.filter(Boolean);
console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

If you *have* to mutate the array in-place, iterate backwards:

```js
const bouncer = (arr) => {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (!arr[i]) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
console.log(bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop from the end of the array because you change the index of the elements by using `splice`.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let i = arr.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (!arr[i]) arr.splice(i, 1);
  }
  console.log(arr)
}
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it with `.filter()` to avoid an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm:

```
let bouncer = (arr) =>
  arr.filter((e) => Boolean(e));
```

When you call it, you'll have to assign the return value to the target array:

```
someArray = bouncer(someArray);
```

Creating a new array is not without cost, but using `.splice()` over and over again on a large input array with many falsey values would be worse.

Note also that you don't really need `Boolean()`; using `!!` implicitly performs a boolean type cast anyway:

```
let bouncer = (arr) =>
  arr.filter((e) => !!e);
```

Comment: I will also add that `arr.filter(Boolean)` works too, but I personally find it slightly less clear than a function. It's a matter of coding style of course.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

> The indexOf() method returns the **first index** at which a given element can be found in the array

Just use [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

you are editing array while looping it, this is causing unexpected behavior:

Update code as follows:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
      let y = []
      for (let i of arr) {
        if (Boolean(i) === false) {
          y.push(i)
        }
      }
      for (let i of y) {
         arr.splice(arr.indexOf(i), 1)
      }
      console.log(arr)
    }
    bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

or better try filter from es6 below:

```js
const data = [7, "ate", "", false, 9]
const filtered = arr => arr.filter(Boolean)
console.log(filtered(data))
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is trying to do. The explicit call to `Boolean()` in the original *converts* values in the array to booleans, and so will remove the empty string also.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let y = []
  for (let i of arr) {
    if (typeof i === 'boolean' && Boolean(i) == false) {
      arr.splice(arr.indexOf(i), 1)
    }
  }
  console.log(arr)
}
bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking, nor does it fix the fundamental problem. Try an array with two `false` values in a row.